# Differentiate $y = x^{\sqrt{x}}$ (Simplification)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

I understand the gist of the problem. Just the simplification confused me.

How did $\sqrt{x}/x$ turn into $1/\sqrt{x}$?

Why does that circled 1 turn into a 2?

Comment: Because $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}=\frac{ad+bc}{bd}$.

Comment: Are you asking why $\frac1{\sqrt x}=\frac2{2\sqrt x}$?

Comment: Because the denominator changed. 1/sqrt(x) = 2/2sqrt(x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively to the above answer:

With regards OP first question.

How does $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}?$

You can see this clearly be considering the powers of said expressions.

The above can be equivalently expressed as

$$ x^{1/2}\cdot x^{-1} = x^{1/2-1} = x^{-1/2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} $$

Answer (score 0):

(1) $\displaystyle \sqrt{x}\cdot\frac{1}{x}=\sqrt{x}\cdot\frac{1}{(\sqrt{x})^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$.

(2) $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{\ln x}{2\sqrt{x}}=\frac{2}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{\ln x}{2\sqrt{x}}=\frac{2}{2\sqrt{x}}+\frac{\ln x}{2\sqrt{x}}=\frac{2+\ln x}{2\sqrt{x}}$.